# How can I get all data in all tables and rows in a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to connect to a SQL Server database, iterate though all tables, then iterate though each row and column to get the values of all data in the database.

I've got this far:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server = P1-012\\ECSQLEXPRESS; Database = DavidsDB; Integrated Security=True");

sqlConn.Open();

DataTable dtSchema = new DataTable();
dtSchema = sqlConn.GetSchema("tables");

foreach(DataRow drCurTable in dtSchema.Rows)
{
    if (drCurTable.ItemArray[3].ToString() == "BASE TABLE")
    {
        // At this point I want to loop though each row in the current table 
        // and get the value for each column in that row.
        MessageBox.Show(drCurTable.ItemArray[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

Somehow I need to reference the current table, iterate through each row, then iterate through each column I believe.

Thanks!

David

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and don't do this to yourself or your server. There is no need to use nested loops for this. What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I would think you don't want to display every value in every row in a message box. You can retrieve all the data a LOT easier then looping.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please edit your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: I do want to get "every value in every row", but no - not in a message box - I'll right it out to a file.  Nested loops seemed easy - if there is a better way (keeping in mind I dont know all the table and column names) I'm all ears!

Comment: Could you just do a database backup and/or script out the database data?

Comment: First get all table names in a list. then write a function to process each table. getting all columns from all rows is just a select * from tableX. you'll get the column names for free in the dataTable. You can then loop over the result set to write out your file, not the database.  Why do you want to do it?

Comment: I think you (TaW) are talking about what I'm missing here - Once I have the list of table names, how to I set a reference to the "current" table?

Comment: I got it now - thanks TaW!

Comment: Why not use SSIS to export the table(s) that you want. This would be a lot less overhead than doing this through c#.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in SQL Server.
Specifically these two which will give you the information you need to query for the tables and then the columns.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

In pure SQL terms you could also do this...

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT * FROM [' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '].[' + [TABLE_NAME] + '];' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```